# Can I make the src attribute fetch base64 data from a server or adjusting server?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have this image tag that must be in an email where I can not use Javascript. How can I make this image tag src fetch base64 data from my API, given that the API is working and written by myself?

```
    <img src="https://qr-generator-test.herokuapp.com/create-qr-code?data=184B2598-E19C- 
    4454-95CE-6BD7498F21D4" style="max-width:300px; width: 100%; padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; display:block;" width="300">
```

Or may be I can edit my API to do something smarter? Any solution?

Comment: Depends on the email engine. Does it accept writing JS code?

Comment: You get a base64 string from that url that is not a valid image!
Just return a valid image instead of the base64 string

Comment: If you want as base64 you need the base64 as the src value. Really not clear what you are doing here

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your answer! I have updated the API to return a valid image (you can check it) but still the img tag isn't loading it. Any idea?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your answer! I need my img tag to show the image no matter what. The API call placed in src attribute was returning base64 image. Now I changed to return a link to a png image. In both cases the image isn't loading.

Comment: @callback Thanks for your answer! No I can't use any JS as said in the question.

Comment: @LeeMoe I Think you mix two things together. Now you dont return a valid image, you just return the url to the image. When you visit: `https://qr-generator-test.herokuapp.com/create-qr-code?data=184B2598-E19C-%204454-95CE-6BD7498F21D4` you get a URL to another image, instead of the image binary data itself. You need to read the content from the file and send it to the client/browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Befor you send the E-Mail to the customer, change the src attr to a valid base64 image:

```html
 <img src="data:image/gif;base64,..." style="max-width:300px; width: 100%; padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; display:block;" width="300">
```

Here you must encode the QR code image binary to base64.

Or set it to your current url and display the image as regular.

```html
 <img src="https://qr-generator-test.herokuapp.com/create-qr-code?data=184B2598-E19C- 
    4454-95CE-6BD7498F21D4" style="max-width:300px; width: 100%; padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; display:block;" width="300">
```

For this you need to return the image binary data on the url, and nothing else.
No url to antoher image, no text, just the plain binary from your QR code.

When i visit: `https://qr-generator-test.herokuapp.com/create-qr-code?data=184B2598-E19C-%204454-95CE-6BD7498F21D4` i get a URL, not a valid image. `https://qr-generator-test.herokuapp.com/qr-code/55m1bnju1367f7.png` points to a QR code image.

I hope i could clarify what your problem is.

Comment: You explained it VERY well and it works for me now. Thanks a ton!